# Is there a quicker way to create a callback than interfaces or handler?

Tags: android, design-patterns

I just want to check if there may be a simpler way to do this.

If I have some generic ASyncTask and it's done I want to pass a success boolean back to the original caller. Normally I create an interface inside the custom AsyncTask class with just one method `void onSuccess(boolean success);`
The caller would implement that and so on.

I just feel that it clutters the project with mini interfaces.

I could also pass along a handler, but I would have to create a handler for only that purpose which often feels like "just a bit too much code for the purpose".

I could pass a runnable along, but I would have to fire it on a thread and that could cause trouble.

What I want I to execute a method of the calling object when the asynctask has finished. In Objective C I can pass along a "block" of code and maybe there is something similar in Android.

It is a theoretical question and there is no urgency, just curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

You can incorporate [event bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_monitoring) into your app, like [GreenRobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), [OTTO](https://square.github.io/otto/) or other available but this still requires some work. I personally still do not see problems creating Interfaces and stuff whenever it makes sense for my project.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I think of is lambdas but since Android doesn't support Java 8 that might be a problem.

If you just need the lambdas and not the other new things in Java 8 you can have a look here:
https://hakanyamanyar.wordpress.com/2014/07/08/using-java-8-lambda-expressions-in-android-developer-tools/

He is basically using a gradle dependency called gradle-retrolambda that allows you to use lambdas in Android. I have not tried this my self though.

Other things that might work for your use case except using Interfaces might be EventBus or Square.io's Otto. They are both based on an publish/subscribe event pattern. I've tried EventBus my self and it's very easy to use and works well.